# Accessing Parent Class Properties from Property Objects

Tags: c#

Say you have the following design:

```
ClassA

ClassC

ClassB
    Property: object of type ClassA
    Property: object of type ClassC
```

If `ClassB` has an object of type `ClassA`, is there any way for `ClassA` to be able to access members of `ClassB`?  In other words, say there is a method of `ClassA` (say `ClassA.GetVegetables()`) but that `ClassA` method needs to access `ClassB`'s property of type `ClassC`, is that possible?

Comment: No with this setup, no. You'll have to restructure your design. What's stopping you from passing it as an argument?

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Isn't that redundant?  I mean, you would have to basically call `ClassBobj.ClassAprop_obj.GetVegetables(ClassBobj.ClassCprop_obj)`.

Comment: Yeah, you have to provide ClassA access to the ClassB instance some how. void ClassA.GetVegitables(ClassB argumentName). Then in ClassB you do PropertyA.GetVegitables(this);

Comment: @user3175663: yes, that is exactly what I would do. It might just be a deeper design flaw though, but we can't tell that without more code.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Perfect, I think I have what I need.  If you put this into an answer I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing any aditional code the best way to approach is by simply passing the required information as an argument to your `GetVegetables` method.

Ideally you should pass all the required data as an argument to make the methods very self-contained without relying on some global state.

This is assuming the current design is optimal; this might be solved just as fine by changing the design details but we can't tell without seeing more code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are mixing 2 concepts together:

- Reference to an instance of an object
- Permission to access members/methods/properties of objects

Whether or not ClassA can call *any* method of ClassB depends on whether ClassA has a reference to ClassB (first concept). This can be achieved by passing an instance of ClassB to ClassA's constructor for example.

Once ClassA has a reference to an instance of ClassB, it can only access methods of ClassB that are marked `public`. Look up `access modifiers` for more information.